# Making p:editor in a p:dialog fit the dialogs size

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I have an p:editor inside a p:dialog. The dialog is dragable and I want the editor to fill all the available space of the dialog. I don't know if this is purely a HTML/CSS problem or if this has something to do with the JSF components I am using. Regarding width, this works fine when I set width: 100% in my child container. When I try the same with height: 100%, it has no effect. Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="frmNote">
            <p:dialog id="dlgNote" widgetVar="dlgNote"
                      header="Note"
                      position="right"
                      style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"
                      dynamic="false" modal="false"
                      fitViewport="false" resizable="true"
                      closable="true" closeOnEscape="true"
                      onHide="$('#frmNote\\:quit').click();">
                        <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('dlgNote').hide();" />
                        <p:editor id="noteEditor" widgetVar="noteEditor"
                                      value="#{backenbean.text}"
                                      style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%; height: 100%"
                                      controls="bold italic underline strikethrough font size color highlight bullets numbering undo redo">
                        </p:editor>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the issue is that the resource dependency "editor.js" from primefaces library, has a default height of 250px:

```
@ResourceDependencies({
    @ResourceDependency(library = "primefaces", name = "editor/editor.css"),
    @ResourceDependency(library = "primefaces", name = "jquery/jquery.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library = "primefaces", name = "jquery/jquery-plugins.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library = "primefaces", name = "core.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library = "primefaces", name = "components.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library = "primefaces", name = "editor/editor.js")
})


public class Editor extends EditorBase {

public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "org.primefaces.component.Editor";
}
```

editor.js =>

```
(function(F){F.cleditor={defaultOptions:{width:"auto",height:250, ...
```

To use the height of the parent dialog, I included the style:"height: inherit" in the Editor primefaces component as follows:

```
   <p:editor id="noteEditor" widgetVar="noteEditor" style="height: inherit"
                     value="#{exampleBean.text}"
                     controls="bold italic underline strikethrough font size color highlight bullets numbering undo redo">
        </p:editor>
```

and included a Javascript function to modify the height from 250px to inherit in the div generated by primefaces (based on your code) when the dialog is showed:

```
  <p:dialog id="dlgNote" widgetVar="dlgNote"
              header="Note"
              position="right"
              minWidth="500" onShow="document.getElementById('noteEditor').getElementsByClassName('ui-editor ui-widget-content')[0].setAttribute('style', 'width: auto; height: inherit');"
              minHeight="500"
              dynamic="false" modal="false"
              fitViewport="false" resizable="true"
              closable="true" closeOnEscape="true"
              onHide="$('#frmNote\\:quit').click();">
        <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('dlgNote').hide();" />

        <p:editor id="noteEditor" widgetVar="noteEditor" style="height: inherit"
                     value="#{exampleBean.text}"
                     controls="bold italic underline strikethrough font size color highlight bullets numbering undo redo">
        </p:editor>
    </p:dialog>
```

and the result:
[image]